# ActiveMQ topic subscription

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

I’m new to ActiveMQ.

I’m accessing a topic from ActiveMQ using C# code. Does the subscription to the topic need to be active all the time when the messages arrive? When the messages arrive in topic and if the subscriber is not active then will I get the message when I start the subscription service later?

Comment: Did you get this issue sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional publish/subscribe semantics dictate:

- The subscription has to exist before the messages are sent.
- You will not receive messages sent previously when you create the subscription later.

This is true for both durable and non-durable subscriptions.

By default a subscription is non-durable and only receives messages while the susbsciber is active.

Howeve, a durable subscription will receive messages even if the subscriber is inactive. This can be helpful so as to not miss messages if the subscriber drops offline for  a short time, but if the subscriber drops offline for a long time then messages may accumulate and consume an inordinate amount of resources.

Comment: is it possible with durable subscription if it’s not active?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a 'Durable Subscription'. This creates a subscription on the broker, so the consumer will receive any messages regardless if connected at the time the message is published.

Comment: Means no need to be active during the message from publisher?

Comment: @ShinojNambiar correct